# USB to RS-422 opto isolated converter

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi

I have to test an inertial measurement unit that uses RS-422 communication standard. I will use a Raspberry Pi with a touchscreen that needs the latest Raspbian, which is the Debian(buster), that as far as I know uses the Linux kernel 5.2.

I have had a look at two USB to RS-422 converters that say that they are supporting Linux 4.xx and Linux 2.4/2.6 respectively.

https://www.data-converters.com/docs/specs/usb-serial-3.pdf
https://www.mev.co.uk/pages/Products/USB-Serial-Converters.html

My questions are:

1. Would these converters work together with the newer Linux kernel?
2. If not could you recommend me a product or simply a good retailer
   who might have what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better of with a RS422 shield for your projects.

An example 
https://thepihut.com/products/rs422-rs485-serial-hat?variant=20063170003006